# Configure Console application to Run in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo

I'm testing DAO classes built for an Web-Based application in Eclipse (Indigo), and in this moment I'd like to do it in console, just for data testing.

When I try to run the test class with the "main" method as Java Application, Eclipse asks me about the application that I want to run.

The problem here is that Eclipse is looking in `org.apache.catalina.startup` package for the classes, probably because I've started the project as a WebBased Application, and now I'm not able to look in `[MyApplication]\build\classes` for the main class.

I did it in another project, but then I didn't have the same problem, maybe because I think that I had started the another project as a Java Application, then transformed it in Web Application (is just a suposition).

How can I properly configure "Debug Configurations" to look after \build\classes to select my main class to test my project? If you cand help, I thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've located the problem. I'm posting here because, despite it was very trivial, would help somebody in the future.

The problem was in the main class statement, which had a mistake in `String[] args`. For this reason, the clas wans't being recognized by the Configurator.